# What is the difference between Serializer and ModelSerializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

What is the difference between django rest framework's Serializer vs ModelSerializer? When do you one or the other? Can I use ModelSerializer for Auth? Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: A model serializer builds a serializer based on a model. That’s about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the Django rest framework serializer is the normal serializer that will be used when building an API with Django. It simply parses data from complex types into JSON or XML.

The model serializer is just the same as the above serializer in the sense that it does the same job, only that it builds the serializer based on the model, making the creation of the serializer easier than building it normally.

Comment: So in other words, explicitly defining CRUD methods (get, post,...) is not required. Or do I misunderstand your meaning?

Answer (score 0):

When you are dealing with Microservice and web services if you want to connect your web services with clients so then you have to use a serializer with whatever the data you mentioned in the model in microservices, so it makes it easy for us to carry the data from client-side. In Microservice you used Modelserializer to create serializer but in Webservice you only use serializer.

Comment: What? This answer does not even make sense.

Answer (score 0):

There are differences between Serializer and ModelSerializer from two key perspectives: behavior and basic structure.

**Behavior Difference:**

In many cases, you'll want serializer classes that closely align with Django model definitions. The ModelSerializer class offers a convenient shortcut to automatically generate a Serializer class with fields that directly correspond to the Model's fields. Here's what distinguishes ModelSerializer from a regular Serializer:

1. **Automatic Field Generation**: ModelSerializer will automatically create a set of fields for you based on the model you provide.
2. **Automatic Validators**: It will also generate validators for the serializer, including unique_together validators and other common validations.
3. **Default Implementations**: ModelSerializer includes simple default implementations for methods like `.create()` and `.update()`.

Source: [Django Rest Framework - ModelSerializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer)

**Basic Difference:**

Another fundamental difference is that a ModelSerializer is constructed from a Django model, while a Serializer is built from a dictionary or custom data structure. Think of a ModelSerializer as being analogous to a ModelForm, as they both derive their structure from a Django model. In contrast, a Serializer is designed around a more generic data structure, like a dictionary or a custom data input.

Thanks for using #Codio!